# How to enable Apache File Caching for Angular universal SSR application

Tags: angular, apache, caching, server-side-rendering

I am setting up a Apache File cache for Angular SSR application in CentOS to reduce the TTFB, and landing page will have have faster load time.

I have tried the following steps:

1. Enable mod_file_cache.so by adding the below line in 00-cache.conf in the /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d directory

   LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
2. Enabled MMAPFile in http.conf

   MMapFile /var/www/html/dist/browser/index.html
3. restarted Apache

Tried loading the site from browser, still TTFB is 2.5 sec for all the request. Ideally it should take some time for first request but the subsequent request should be faster from Cache.

Am i missing something here. Is there any other better approach to reduce the TTFB for the Angular SSR application.

TIA